# Symfony 1.4: Doctrine i18n generator issues

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I have a weird problem with my i18n doctrine schema and i.a. the admin generator.

***(Please look at the edit part below first)***

The schema looks like:

```
CargoSize:
  connection: doctrine
  actAs:
    Timestampable:      ~
    I18n:
      fields:                   [name, linkname, seoname, description]
  tableName: com_cargo_size
  columns:
    id:                                     { type: integer(11), notnull: true, unsigned: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name:                                   { type: string(50),  notnull: true }
    linkname:                               { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    seoname:                                { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    description:                            { type: string(255), notnull: true }
```

**The first problem I have with sfForms:**

```
new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'CargoSize', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false), array('style' => 'list-style-type: none; display: inline;'))
```

This generates a radio butten set with the correct IDs, but empty name values.
Even when I try to get the name value by directly selecting a CargoSize object by ID and LANG, getName() always returns an empty string (the DB is filled correctly with suitable data).

So is somethng worng with the schema definition??

**The second problem appears with the admin-generator:**

```
php symfony doc:generate-admin --module=cargo_size admin CargoSize
```

The generator.yml looks like:

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           CargoSize
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          cargo_size
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:
        display: [name, lang]
      filter:  ~
      form:    ~
      edit:
        display: [name]
      new:     ~
```

The funny thing is, that the list view shows me the i18n name. But in edit view I always get the error *"widget 'name' does not exist"*.

Do you guys have any idea why this happens? I would be very thankful for your help.

**EDIT:**

I think the problem sits deeper, because this simple peace of code does note work:

First the datasets for the examples:

```
cargo_size
id  created_at              updated_at
1   2010-04-22 21:37:44     2010-04-22 21:37:44

cargo_size_translation
id      name    linkname    seoname     description     lang
1       klein   klein       klein       klein           de
1       small   small       small       small           en

$c = Doctrine::getTable('CargoSize')->findOneBy('id', 1); 
echo $c;  // (toString exists)

// Output: Catchable fatal error: Method CargoSize::__toString() 
// must return a string value in 
// /var/www/.../apps/frontend/modules/start/templates/indexSuccess.php on line 1

echo $c->getName();
// Output: nothing
```

Does somebody has any idea? I'm really deperated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug. For some reason the culture was set to "**de_DE**" instead of just "de".
With this setting the i18n behavior stuff didn't work!

Answer (score 2):

**First problem :**

The "names values" displayed are taken from the __toString() method result.
You could add the "method" options, like this :

```
new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'CargoSize', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'method' => 'getName'), array('style' => 'list-style-type: none; display: inline;'))
```

**Second problem :**

Your form must embed the i18n form. To do this, put this in the configure method :

```
$this->embedI18n($cultures);
```

where $cultures is an array of your cultures codes.

Comment: This is funny, the toString I already had. But now after adding the embedI18n, all problems seems to be solved, not only in the sfForm, also in form independet places O_o. So thx a lot for this hint :)

Comment: The problem sadly still exsits, I don't know why, but when I want to get the name attribute with:

  $cargo_size->getName(); // (The values are in the DB for each langugae)

It returns an empty string.

Do you have more ideas what the problem could be?